# Regex to capture all vars between delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

How do I capture all 1, 2 and 3 in `not |1|2|3|`

My regex `\|(.*?)\|` skips 2.

```js
const re = /\|(.*?)\|/gi;
const text = 'not |1|2|3|'

console.log(text.match(re).map(m => m[1]));
```

Comment: So, the problem here looks to be with the pattern *and* the code, too. `.map(m => m[1])` only returns the first char of each match, and the second `\|` in the pattern is a part of a consuming pattern, so there is no way the regex can match subsequent matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const re = /\|([^|]*)(?=\|)/g;
const text = 'not |123|2456|37890|'

console.log(Array.from(text.matchAll(re), m => m[1]));
```

*Details*:

- `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^|]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `|`
- `(?=\|)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with `|`.

If you do not care about matching the `|` on the right, you can remove the lookahead.

If you also need to match till the end of string when the trailing `|` is missing, you can use `/\|([^|]*)(?=\||$)/g`.